# How to programmatically determine if an IP is from a hosting/cloud provider, or normal ISP?

Tags: dns, ip

We would like to automatically detect if an IP address assessing our website belong to ISP Local Company (ADSL/Cable/etc) or cloud / hosting company.

What is the most efficient why to do that? I see that Stripe is doing that but I'm not sure what they do that.

Comment: I would advise against using the term "normal ISP" since there is nothing abnormal to be a hosting/cloud provider. In all cases this is not something you can do without false positives/negatives (think proxies for example) so it depends on your goals, that you do not state. But you could apply heuristics on the reverse name, use RIR IP blocks whois data, for 2 starters.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool named which-cloud:

*CLI instalation:*

`npm i which-cloud -g`

*how to use:*

`$ which-cloud \<IP address\>`

`$ which-cloud 104.196.27.39`

**gce**

There are other forms of use, like javascript module import or as an API.

Project Link:
https://github.com/bcoe/which-cloud

Answer (score 0):

Below should be the process to find it out.

1. Have a list of major hosting provider, and keep it in an array or any other datastructure.
2. Do a whois lookup on the IP address by command - `whois xxx.xxx.xxx.xx`
3. run a for look on the array of hosting providers on the result and you will have your answer.